# Running a Win XP scanner driver on CrossOver

Tags: windows, compatibility, scanning

I have a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard.

I own a scanner that was discontinued a couple of years ago (a Mustek A3 USB), and that comes only with drivers for Windows XP, Vista, and Mac OS 9.

I am using CodeWeavers' [CrossOver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrossOver) and was wondering whether it is possible to install a scanner driver in a CrossOver flask, and utilize a Windows program to scan images with it? I'm not quite sure what aspects of Windows CrossOver emulates (it's not a full Windows kernel after all), and whether scanner support is possible.

<sub>I am aware of the "normal" way to do this - using VirtualBox to set up a virtual machine with Windows XP in it. This is the way I will go if all else fails; using CrossOver would just be so much more convenient than setting up a full Windows machine....</sub>

<sub>The scanner is old, but high-quality and huge (A3 Format), so buying a new one isn't really an option.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CrossOver doesn't emulate or simulate hardware - it just translates a subset of the Windows API - just enough to fool normal apps. You'll want something like VirtualBox, Parallels or VMWare Fusion to scan directly into Windows.

Since VirtualBox is free, start there and then spend money on a commercial solution if or when your time becomes more scarce than your budget.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this would be the case. Virtualbox it is then, thanks!